# HTML and Flex Viewer 2.5

Tags: arcgis-flex-viewer

I was wondering if it is possible to customize the interface of the Flex viewer with HTML using the index.html file that is located in the viewer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flex Viewer is an embedded SWF file that is wrapped up within an HTML file.
By default the SWF is set to 100% width and height.
It is possible to add banners, logos, etc around the SWF content.

I could not find a FlexViewer example, but [this is a Esri Flex app](https://maps.bayswater.wa.gov.au/Dekho3External/) - click View Source on the blue html header/footer.

Personally, I prefer to directly modify the look and feel of the Flex app, and this has been a made a lot easier since the Flex 4 SDK with skinning.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I modify the default.htm to add logo and company info.